# search mongoDB by 2 fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been looking at some other answers on stack overflow and got as far as I could with that. I learnt that I need to create a text index where I define my Schema which I did like this:

```
productSchema.index({'title': 'text', 'address.city': 'text'});
```

If I search by just 1 field, ie: title then I get results as I expect.

```
Product.find( { $text: { $search: searchTerm } } )
```

But there is something wrong with my query when trying to search by title and city together.

```
 Product.find( { $text: { $search: searchTerm }, $text: { $search: city } } )
```

I see no error but I get no results even though I know there should be results for my query. I am not sure if it is because address is an object (according to what I see in Compass)

This is how I defined it in my schema using Mongoose

```
address: {
    city: {type: String, required: true }
},
```

If I do this:

```
Product.find().and([{ title: searchTerm }, { 'address.city': city }])
```

it almost works. But I have to type in the exact title of the product. If the product is called "a rubber duck" and I type in "duck" I get no results. If I type in "a rubber duck" and select the city it is listed in I get back a result.

I have just also tried this:

```
Product.find( { $and: [ {$text: { $search: searchTerm }}, { address: {city : city } }  ] } )
```

Which seems to work but could probably be improved upon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the link below? 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
There you can find how to add multiple expressions in same query.
If you want to search for titles where title might be equal to A or to B use a query like this: `db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { title: "A" }, { title: "B"} ] } )`.
**Edit** 
If you need data from db to match both expressions in query then use something like this:
`Product.find( { $and: [{ address:{city: "CityName"} }, { address: {country : "UK" } }  ] } )`

Comment: thanks for the link. I normally check the Mongoose documentation but I find the mongo db documentation is much better. Difficult to find things in the Mongoose documentation, well I find it difficult anyway. And I am trying to be consistent and use the mongoose syntax as it differs from mongo

Comment: Well I gave you an example of how you can use for your related problem

Comment: shouldn't it be AND instead of OR as both conditions need to be met

Comment: If both conditions should met, then yes it is AND , I will edit my post

Comment: thanks for that. I am testing it now but getting an error which I will try debug as well. unknown top level operator: $search

Comment: If you have a schema and one column in schema has also multiple columns then I don't know how you should refer to a particular column from multiple columns. But if you schema would just have 2 columns like , city and country , you just would do something like this `Product.find( { $and: [{ city: "London"}, { country: "UK"} ] } )`

Comment: Yeah, that is the tricky part because I can't type `address.city: "London"` for example

Comment: tried your new code and just modified it to my needs: `Product.find( { $and: [{ title: searchTerm} , { address: {city : city } }  ] } )` but I have the same issue. If I type 'duck' I get no results. If I type 'A rubber duck' I get results.

Comment: I think I might have got it. But it seems a bit long winded. `Product.find( { $and: [ {$text: { $search: searchTerm }}, { address: {city : city } }  ] } )`

Comment: is it valid mongoose syntax though?

Comment: What you mean by valid ?

Comment: it looks more like mongoDB syntax than mongoose. I am mixing syntax here aren't I? This is mongoose `Product.find().and([{ title: searchTerm }, { 'address.city': city }])` it is .and instead of $and

Comment: Well it might be, I use mongoose too, but when I need to query I am only using MongoDb . It might be just with what you feel more confortable